# How to determine active monitor of the current pseudo-terminal in Linux shell?

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line-interface, xorg, konsole

All is in the title, I would like to know the current monitor to rename the `KDE Konsole` title accordingly to his position (left or right).

This way I will put in `~/.bashrc` or such by example :

```
qdbus org.kde.konsole $KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION org.kde.konsole.Session.setTitle \
    1 "LEFT"
```

to change the title of the `Konsole`.

I took a look to the man pages of :

- xdotool
- xprop

And I play around `qdbus`, but I'm just able to find the current desktop with

```
qdbus org.kde.kwin /KWin org.kde.KWin.currentDesktop
```

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn libXrandr and/or the `xrandr` command.

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/randrproto/tree/randrproto.txt

You'll discover that your window can be fully inside both monitors at the same time, or even outside the view of both monitors.

You need to discover which CRTC is being used by each output and then the area of the framebuffer covered by the CRTC. Then you need to discover where in the framebuffer your application is.

I'm not sure if there's any easier or even kde-specific way of doing this.